# Oracle Join two enormous table

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, temp

I have Oracle procedure which consists of some EXECUTE IMMEDIATE blocks. One of them - join two big table(~100-200,000,000 records):

```
 v_sql:='create table idb.cm_contact_add_char_exp_tmp as  
select ch.* from idb.cm_contact_add_char_exp ch  join
idb.communication_contact_exp_tmp cont on  cont.customer_rk=ch.customer_rk and ch.RESPONSE_TRACK_CD=cont.RESPONSE_TRACK_CD'

execute immediate v_sql;
```

First table(CH) has index on (CUSTOMER_RK,RESPONSE_TRACK_CD) and partition on date.

SQL_PLAN:
[image]

Oracle gives the following error:

> SQL Error: ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 64 in
>   tablespace TEMP

Comment: I'm not sure the dynamic aspect is relevant to the question. Surely you would have the same issue without it.

Comment: Is there any filter you can apply, such as the partition date you mentioned? Currently you are joining both tables in their entirety (4384 partitions). Assuming data grows constantly, unless you have some routine purge process this will always eventually reach a point where it exceeds the resources available.

Comment: So, what is the problem with dynamic queries?

Comment: It adds complexity, and hides errors and dependencies until runtime. From the point of view of your [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) though, it seems to be unnecessary detail.

Comment: Can I fix error with temp segment, if I change it to SQL query?

Comment: Being dynamic or static doesn't affect the amount of resources used, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but the main question is - how to fix the error. Could you help me with it?

Comment: Do you really need to process all 4384 partitions at once? Can you do it in batches? Normally though batches like this are only done for s specific day, so I wondered whether you were missing a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to enlarge temporary tablespace (which, though, might not be enough anyway), or create table first and insert data partially, especially as you said there's partition there.

By the way, why do you create table that way? It is unusual; generally speaking, you should create table in SQL, not PL/SQL.

Comment: Do you think that only PL/SQL blocks create large temp segments?

Comment: What made you think that I think that? I said that the OP shouldn't CREATE TABLE using PL/SQL; there's rarely a good reason for doing that so I suggested to do it in SQL. Once the table is created, insert data into it. As source tables contain vast millions of rows and are partitioned, INSERT INTO might be done in "chunks" so that TEMP tablespace wouldn't explode.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to first dynamically create the table - if that is really what you need - using

```
CREATE TABLE idb.cm_contact_add_char_exp_tmp AS
SELECT ch.*
  FROM idb.cm_contact_add_char_exp ch  
 WHERE 1=0
```

Then use bulk FORALL operations to insert the records from the source tables.

I would question why you need what looks like a temporary table containing around 200Million rows though. Sounds a bit suspect to me.

Comment: Do you think that only PL/SQL blocks create large temp segments? I suppose the main problem is large join